# Microsoft Server Backup Training

Tags: backup

I was curious as to if anyone knew the quickest and most reliable way to locate someone certified in training for MS Server Backup?

I need to locate a Microsoft Partner that can train and/or implement the usage of MS's server backup tools.

Thank you.

Comment: are you talking about DPM?

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft Pinpoint is your friend.

For you, I searched "Backup" in Kansas (gleaned from your profile)..
http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/companies/search?q=backup&fl=kansas&fcrc=USA

This is probably the best way to find a certified partner to help you.

Comment: @JoeJMCIT Care to click the big Tick button if you liked my answer?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a certification for just Microsoft backup tools. However, anyone who has any MCSE/MCITP:EA certified people would easily be able to assist.

Comment: There's an MCTS for it : MCTS: System Center Data Protection Manager 2007, Configuration, exam # 658

Answer (score 1):

There's a huge difference between a MS certified trainer, and an MS certified engineer.

If you're a client that needs work done, you would hire the latter, and as part of the contract you would be smart to specify "documentation and knowledge transfer", so that your in-house folks would learn something from the person doing it.

You would not hire the former (a trainer) to come in and do a project; they would come in and teach a class, using the microsoft curriculum for the product  - in this case, MCTS: System Center Data Protection Manager 2007, Configuration (for exam# 658).